# int() argument must be string, a bytes-like object, not 'ObjectId'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am following this [tutorial](https://bezkoder.com/django-mongodb-crud-rest-framework/#Source_code) for using MongoDB and Django with djongo. I am having an error creating the items of this model, but I am following the tutorial closely and I don´t really know what´s the problem. I show here the code from the models, the views and the serializer:

```
class Piso(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False,default='');
habitantes = models.CharField(max_length=202,blank=False,default='');


class PisoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Piso
    fields = ('id','nombre','habitantes')
```

And the view method:

```
@api_view(['POST','GET'])
def piso_list(request):
# GET list of tutorials, POST a new tutorial, DELETE all tutorials
if request.method == 'POST':
    piso_serializer = PisoSerializer(data=request.data)
    if piso_serializer.is_valid():
        piso_serializer.save();#This is the object I fill
        return JsonResponse(piso_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED) 
    return JsonResponse(piso_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
elif request.method == 'GET':
    pisos = Piso.objects.all()

    name = request.GET.get('name', None)
    if name is not None:
        pisos = pisos.filter(nombre__icontains=name)

    pisos_serializer = PisoSerializer(pisos, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(pisos_serializer.data[0], safe=False)
    # 'safe=False' for objects serialization
```

The problem is that the object does not save the id column of my object in the database, which is created automatically. This is the object the MongoDB saves:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5edd1014b9ca43bdef186d38"
},
"nombre": "iddyo",
"habitantes": "yeto"
}
```

It´s probably a stupid error but I can´t get my head around it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Likely the serializer does not understand that it is a varchar. What if you add `id = models.CharField(max_length=24, primary_key=True)` to the model?

Comment: it works with that, but it does not fix the problem which is that django is supposed to create a id autofield automatically, so the object should have a field called "id" :123, for example. If I put the id field manually it gives me the same error

Comment: it does, but it uses an `IntegerField`, and `5edd1014b9ca43bdef186d38`  is not a valid value for an integer field.

Comment: ah,ok so it seems like it uses the objectId instead of creating an id itself, thanks for answering